# Left join polymorphic relation Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a system where a check-in can belong to a user subscription (relation between user and subscription plan) or to the user directly.

I wanted to retrieve the last check-in made by a user so I decided to do an advanced left join to get the check-ins of both instances (user and user subscription) but when I run the query the result set is empty.

```php
/**
             * Get the checkins for the user
             */
            ->leftJoin('user_subscriptions', 'user_subscriptions.user_id', 'users.id')
            ->leftJoin('checkins', function ($join) {
                $join->on('checkins.checkinable_id', '=', DB::raw('users.id AND checkins.checkinable_type = "' . User::class . '"'))
                    ->orOn('checkins.checkinable_id', '=', DB::raw('user_subscriptions.id AND checkins.checkinable_type = "' . UserSubscription::class . '"'));
            })
```

this would be the query when I join the check-ins table to get all the check-ins from a specific user. What I discovered with trial and error is that if I delete this part:

```php
AND checkins.checkinable_type = "' . User::class . '"
```

I get the right results mixed with some bad associations (user.id = checkinable_id from a user subscription type). At this point I don't understand what I would be doing wrong.

I'll leave the whole query here in case it helps somehow:

```php
$gyms = Gym::whereHas('schedulers', function ($query) {

            /**
             * Is notification enabled
             */
            $query->where('slug', 'giorni-di-assenza-di-allenamento')
                ->where('enabled', true); // Pivot
        })

            /**
             * Get users
             */
            ->leftJoin('users_gyms', 'users_gyms.gym_id', 'gyms.id')
            ->leftJoin('users', 'users.id', 'users_gyms.user_id')
            ->whereNull('users_gyms.deleted_at')
            ->whereNull('users.deleted_at')

            /**
             * Remove dead users- gyms relations
             */
            ->whereNotNull('users.id')

            /**
             * Get the checkins for the user
             */
            ->leftJoin('user_subscriptions', 'user_subscriptions.user_id', 'users.id')
            ->leftJoin('checkins', function ($join) {
                $join->on('checkins.checkinable_id', '=', DB::raw('users.id AND checkins.checkinable_type = "' . User::class . '"'))
                    ->orOn('checkins.checkinable_id', '=', DB::raw('user_subscriptions.id AND checkins.checkinable_type = "' . UserSubscription::class . '"'));
            })

            /**
             * Get lessons for the checkin dates
             */
            ->leftJoin('lesson_details', 'lesson_details.id', 'checkins.lesson_detail_id')

            /**
             * At least one checkin
             */
            ->whereNotNull('lesson_details.date')

            /**
             * Get only the already checked in ones
             */
            ->where('lesson_details.date', '<=', Carbon::today())
            ->whereNull('checkins.deleted_at')

            ->groupBy('users.id', 'gyms.id')

            /**
             * Get all we need
             */
            ->selectRaw('MAX(lesson_details.date) as last_checkin, users.id as user_id, gyms.id as gym_id')
            ->get();
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after 30 minutes more of back and forth I discovered that the advanced join must be like this:

```php
/**
 * Get the checkins for the user
 */
->leftJoin('user_subscriptions', 'user_subscriptions.user_id', 'users.id')
->leftJoin('checkins', function ($join) {
    $join->on('checkins.checkinable_id', '=', 'users.id')
        ->where('checkins.checkinable_type', User::class)
        ->orOn('checkins.checkinable_id', '=', 'user_subscriptions.id')
        ->where('checkins.checkinable_type', UserSubscription::class);
})
```

without any `DB::raw`